# Should std::hash<T> work when T is std::pair<two simpler types also supported by std::hash>?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stl, stdhash

I was using an ordered set declared as so:

```
std::set<std::pair<const std::string, const myClass *> > myset;
```

After doing some analysis of the way I was using the `set,` I concluded that an `unordered_set` would be a smarter choice. But when I changed `std::set` to `std::unordered_set`, I got a vast spew of error messages from my compiler (g++ 4.8.1) complaining of an

```
invalid use of incomplete type struct std::hash<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, const myClass * > >
```

I figured out that `std::hash` didn't know how to deal with a type which was `std::pair`, despite the fact that the two types that made up the `pair` were each hashable. I think [error for hash function of pair of ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590656/error-for-hash-function-of-pair-of-ints) contains relevant information about the C++11 standard that explains why things went awry. (There's no good explanation for the impenetrable wall of error text that g++ emits for this.)

It would seem to me that

```
std::hash<std::pair<T1, T2>> hasher(make_pair(x,y))
  = some_func(std::hash<T1>hasher(x), std::hash<T2>hasher(y) )
```

where `some_func()` could be as simple as XOR (or not; see [Why is XOR the default way to combine hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889238/why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes))

Is there a good reason for the standard to not require `std::hash` to know how to construct a hash value for an object which is a `pair` of types that are each hashable?

Comment: Can you hash `const myClass *`?  Or can you only hash `const myClass`?

Comment: There's a [proposal](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3980.html) that addresses this issue. Other than that, this question is too broad and not really answerable. For now, you can provide your own `std::hash` specialization and use `boost::hash_combine` to combine the individual hashes.

Comment: Please feel free to use the software behind the proposal that Praetorian references:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/hash_append  Just in the past couple of days my team as benefited from the ability to easily compare hash algorithm X with hash algorithm Y, as applied to our specific application, and choose which one is best for us.

Comment: [XOR is a crappy way to combine hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27952689/1774667)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple, it was not added to the standard.  The same is true of hashing other  structures like `tuple`.

Things tend to be added to the standard when they are good enough, not when they are perfect, as perfection is the enemy of the good.  More specializations of `std::hash` are not things that will break code (that often), so adding new ones is relatively harmless.

In any case, to that end, we can write our own hash extenders.  As an example:

```
namespace hashers {
  constexpr size_t hash_combine( size_t, size_t ); // steal from boost, or write your own
  constexpr size_t hash_combine( size_t a ) { return a; }
  constexpr size_t hash_combine() { return 0; }
  template<class...Sizes>
  constexpr size_t hash_combine( size_t a, size_t b, Sizes... sizes ) {
    return hash_combine( hash_combine(a,b), sizes... );
  }

  template<class T=void> struct hash;

  template<class A, class B>
  constexpr size_t custom_hash( std::pair<A,B> const& p ) {
    return hash_combine( hash<size_t>{}(2), hash<std::decay_t<A>>{}(p.first), hash<std::decay_t<B>>{}(p.second) );
  }
  template<class...Ts, size_t...Is>
  constexpr size_t custom_hash( std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::tuple<Ts...> const& p ) {
    return hash_combine( hash<size_t>{}(sizeof...(Ts)), hash<std::decay_t<Ts>>{}(std::get<Is>(p))... );
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  constexpr size_t custom_hash( std::tuple<Ts...> const& p ) {
    return custom_hash( std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, p );
  }
  template<class T0, class C>
  constexpr size_t custom_hash_container( size_t n, C const& c) {
    size_t retval = hash<size_t>{}(n);
    for( auto&& x : c)
      retval = hash_combine( retval, hash<T>{}(x) );
    return retval;
  }
  template<class T0, class C>
  constexpr size_t custom_hash_container( C const& c) {
    return custom_hash_container( c.size(), c );
  }
  template<class T, class...Ts>
  size_t custom_hash( std::vector<T, Ts...> const& v ) {
    return custom_hash_container<T>(v);
  }
  template<class T, class...Ts>
  size_t custom_hash( std::basic_string<T, Ts...> const& v ) {
    return custom_hash_container<T>(v);
  }
  template<class T, size_t n>
  constexpr size_t custom_hash( std::array<T, n> const& v ) {
    return custom_hash_container<T>(n, v);
  }
  template<class T, size_t n>
  constexpr size_t custom_hash( T (const& v)[n] ) {
    return custom_hash_container<T>(n, v);
  }
  // etc -- list, deque, map, unordered map, whatever you want to support
  namespace details {
    template<class T, class=void>
    struct hash : std::hash<T> {};
    using hashers::custom_hash;
    template<class T>
    struct hash<T,decltype(void(
      custom_hash(declval<T const&>())
    )) {
      constexpr size_t operator()(T const& t)const {
        return custom_hash(t);
      }
    };
  }
  template<class T>
  struct hash : details::hash<T> {};
  template<>
  struct hash<void> {
    template<class T>
    constexpr size_t operator()(T const& t)const { return hash<T>{}(t); }
  }
}
```

and now `hashers::hash<T>` will recursively use either an ADL-looked up `custom_hash` function, or `std::hash` if that fails, to hash `T` and its components, and `hashers::hash<>` is a universal hasher that tries to hash anything passed to it.

Code may not compile as shown.

I chose to hash all containers and tuples as hash their length, followed by hashing the combination of their contents.  As a side effect, `array<int, 3>` hashes the same as `tuple<int,int,int>`, and `tuple<int,int>` hashes the same as `pair<int,int>`, and `std::vector<char>{'a','b','c', '\0'}` hashes the same as `"abc"`, which I think is a nice property.  The empty array/tuple/vector/etc hashes like `size_t(0)`.

You can extend the above system for your own types by simply overriding `custom_hash` in the namespace of the type in question, or specializing either `std::hash<X>` or `hashers::hash<X>` to do your custom hash (I would go with `std::hash` for the principle of least surprise myself).  For advanced use, you can specialize `hashers::details::hash<X,void>` with SFINAE, but I'd say do it for `custom_hash` instead.

Comment: Better hashing framework, no need for hash combining: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html

Comment: Caveat: writing a custom hash for unordered containers should respect their nontrivial `==`

Comment: @Caleth I'm not sure where that Caveat is addressing.  If two unordered containers return `==` true, your hash has to be the same, but I don't see any advice or implementation above that disagrees with that.  Can you point it out?

Comment: The naive `hash_combine_range(unordered.begin(), unordered.end())` won't necessarily work

Comment: @caleth ah, because two unordered containers with different bucket counts iterate differently.