# How to get identical pairs from two vectors in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I define two vectors: 
`std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec1` and `std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec2`.

I want to find same pairs from `vec1` and `vec2`. 
For example, `vec1 = {{1,2}, {1,9}, {2,13}, {3,5}}`,
`vec2 = {{8, 7}, {4,2}, {2,10}, {1,9}}`. Then the result should be `{{1,9}}`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

You could do it if you sort your vectors with [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and then use [std::set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) to find their common elements in the following way:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v1 {{1,2}, {1,9}, {2,13}, {3,5}};
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v2 {{8,7}, {4,2}, {2,10} ,{1,9}};

std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v_intersection;
std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(v_intersection));
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c355795d15eb756)

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by 42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001938/3182664) has a running time of O(n*log(n)) for the sorting process of the two vectors (where `n` is the size of the larger vector). If this is an issue, you can also create an [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and fill it with the elements of one vector, and then use [`copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to retain only the elements from the other vector that are also contained in the `set`, resulting in a running time of O(n).

```
struct pairhash {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T, U>& p) const {
        return std::hash<T>()(p.first) ^ std::hash<U>()(p.second);
    }
};
struct pairequal {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()(const std::pair<T, U>& p0, const std::pair<T, U>& p1) const {
        return (p0.first == p1.first) && (p0.second == p1.second);
    }
};

void findEqualPairs() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec1{ { 1, 2 }, { 1, 9 }, { 2, 13 }, { 3, 5 } };
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec2{ { 8, 7 }, { 4, 2 }, { 2, 10 }, { 1, 9 } };

    std::unordered_set<std::pair<int, int>, pairhash, pairequal> set2(
        vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> intersection;
    std::copy_if(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(),
        std::back_inserter(intersection),
        [&](const std::pair<int, int>& p) { 
            return set2.find(p) != set2.end(); });

    std::cout << "intersection:" << std::endl;
    for (auto it : intersection) {
        std::cout << it.first << ", " << it.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

(The `pairhash` is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590656/error-for-hash-function-of-pair-of-ints))