# Is it possible to use a HashSet as the key to a HashMap?

Tags: hashmap, rust

I would like to use a `HashSet` as the key to a `HashMap`. Is this possible?

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn main() {
    let hmap: HashMap<HashSet<usize>, String> = HashMap::new();
}
```

gives the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::collections::HashSet<usize>: std::hash::Hash` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:4:49
  |
4 |     let hmap: HashMap<HashSet<usize>, String> = HashMap::new();
  |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::hash::Hash` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashSet<usize>`
  |
  = note: required by `<std::collections::HashMap<K, V>>::new`
```

Comment: It's possible to use a `BTreeSet` as a key to a `HashMap`, since `BTreeSet` implements the appropriate traits. I know this isn't strictly an answer to the original question, but it seems within the scope, anyway: the original question was precisely what I went looking for, but a `BTreeSet` was, for me, a perfectly fine answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To make something the key of a `HashMap`, you need to satisfy 3 traits:

1. `Hash` — How do you calculate a hash value for the type?
2. `PartialEq` — How do you decide if two instances of a type are the same?
3. `Eq` — Can you guarantee that the equality is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive? This requires `PartialEq`.

This is based on the definition of `HashMap`:

```
impl<K: Hash + Eq, V> HashMap<K, V, RandomState> {
    pub fn new() -> HashMap<K, V, RandomState> { /* ... */ }
}
```

Checking out the docs for [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html), you can see what traits it implements (listed at the bottom of the page).

There isn't an implementation of `Hash` for `HashSet`, so it cannot be used as a key in a `HashMap`. That being said, if you have a rational way of computing the hash of a `HashSet`, then you could create a "newtype" around the `HashSet` and implement these three traits on it.

Here's an example for the "newtype":

```
use std::{
    collections::{HashMap, HashSet},
    hash::{Hash, Hasher},
};

struct Wrapper<T>(HashSet<T>);

impl<T> PartialEq for Wrapper<T>
where
    T: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Wrapper<T>) -> bool {
        self.0 == other.0
    }
}

impl<T> Eq for Wrapper<T> where T: Eq + Hash {}

impl<T> Hash for Wrapper<T> {
    fn hash<H>(&self, _state: &mut H)
    where
        H: Hasher,
    {
        // do something smart here!!!
    }
}

fn main() {
    let hmap: HashMap<Wrapper<u32>, String> = HashMap::new();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It affirms that there is a lot I need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `Hash` for a HashMap or HashSet is easier thank you think.
To compute a hash, we can simply add together the hashes of each element in the `HashSet` (or key-value pair in the `HashMap`).

**EDIT:** *Based on this solution, I decided to publish a crate [hash-that-set](https://crates.io/crates/hash-that-set) on crates.io. It allows wrapping hash maps and sets in `SumHashes::new(my_set_or_map)`. This wrapper includes everything from the solution below, plus better interoperability with standard traits.*

Notes:

- Hashing each element, as we do, is slightly atypical, since we must recreate the hasher each time.
- It's possible to parameterize our `Hash` implementation on the `BuildHasher` associated with the HashMap/HashSet.
- Deref and DerefMut make wrappers easier to work with. In general, these traits should be used with care, because they make the outer type look and talk like the inner type.
- The following code works for both HashSet and HashMap, the latter with some adaptation.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct HashSetWrapper<O: Eq + Hash + PartialEq>(HashSet<O>);

impl<O: Eq + Hash + PartialEq> Hash for HashSetWrapper<O> {
    // IMPLEMENTING HASH HERE
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        // Use Wrapping<u64> to allow wrapping overflow
        let mut sum = Wrapping::default();
        for value in &self.0 {
            let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
            Hash::hash(value, &mut hasher);
            sum += hasher.finish();
        }
        state.write_u64(sum.0);
    }
}

impl<O: Eq + Hash + PartialEq> Deref for HashSetWrapper<O> {
    type Target = HashSet<O>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<O: Eq + Hash + PartialEq> DerefMut for HashSetWrapper<O> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.0
    }
}
```

Fun fact: this implementation is actually the same that Java uses for `java.util.HashMap` and `java.util.HashSet`. I had been thinking about the problem in Rust until I remembered what Java did.

Comment: What makes addition better than, say, XOR?

Comment: Good question @leo848. I didn't think of XOR, but another SO question seems to answer why XOR is not the preferred technique to combine hashes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952689

Comment: Both points from the linked post are irrelevant in this case as a HashSet is already unique, and commutatively is actively wanted.

Comment: Referring to that post, it's important to keep in mind that pairwise identical *hashes*, not necessarily elements, would map to 0. Two elements can generate the same hash; depending on the hasher impl and the Hash::hash impl, this can be more or less common. E.g., I've seen code which uses an ID integer for its hash, but considers other fields in the equality coomparison.