# HashSet as key for other HashSet

Tags: hash, rust, hashset

Im trying to use a `HashSet<String>` as a key for other `HashSet`.
I have found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828487/hashmap-with-hashset-as-key) that points out to implement the `Hash` trait for `HashSet<String>`, but I couldn't make my specific case to work.

My case is luckily more bound so what I need is:

- Implement the `hash` trait **only** for the type `HashSet<String>`
- The hashing should be very simple for now:

The set `{"q3", "q1", "q2"}` should be hashed as a simple ordered, joined string version of it, something like `hash("q1-q2-q3")`. Obtaining `"q1-q2-q3"` is not a problem but using it inside a `hash` throws all sort of errors I could not deal with.

This is my attempt of implementation, but it doesn't work. I think that the `StateSet` wrapper is not the right way of doing it, because I lose all the important `HashSet` methods

```
use std::collections::{HashMap,HashSet};
use std::hash::{Hash,Hasher};

type State = String;
struct StateSet(HashSet<State>);

impl PartialEq for StateSet {
    fn eq(&self, other: &StateSet) -> bool {
        self.is_subset(&other) && other.is_subset(&self) 
    }
}

impl Eq for StateSet {}

impl Hash for StateSet {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) where H: Hasher {
        let a: Vec<State> = self.iter().collect();
        a.sort();
        for s in a.iter() {
            s.hash(state);
        }
    }

}

fn main() {
    let hmap: HashSet<StateSet> = HashSet::new(); 
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8a2b74b444d3e3ad652f77487b235d55&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several problems with your code, the main ones being that you were trying to access methods on `HashSet` by calling them on your newtype wrapper. You need to call them on the `HashSet` directly by replacing `self` with `self.0`. Here's the final working code:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap,HashSet};
use std::hash::{Hash,Hasher};

type State = String;
struct StateSet(HashSet<State>);

impl PartialEq for StateSet {
    fn eq(&self, other: &StateSet) -> bool {
        self.0.is_subset(&other.0) && other.0.is_subset(&self.0) 
    }
}

impl Eq for StateSet {}

impl Hash for StateSet {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) where H: Hasher {
        let mut a: Vec<&State> = self.0.iter().collect();
        a.sort();
        for s in a.iter() {
            s.hash(state);
        }
    }

}

fn main() {
    let hmap: HashSet<StateSet> = HashSet::new(); 
}
```

Also, I would highly recommend you to use [`BTreeSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html) here, which implements `Hash` as it stores the elements in a sorted order. Its `Hash` implementation should definitely be faster than your implementation which does an `O(n log(n))` sort of all items.

Comment: Minor nits: `Vec<_>` and `for s in a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dogbert! Im going to mark your answer as the correct one.
Here is a little working example using your code https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=faad68f658e11f94ada25b6b0e8704f4&version=stable&backtrace=0

I will be reading more about BTreeSet to see if it fits my use case, thanks a lot!

Comment: Dogbert: I've tested BTreeSet and they are _exactly_ what I was looking for. Because the set's Im dealing with require ordering in some parts of my code so they fit naturally. Also, I dont need to implement the Hash trait with which make things even easier. Thanks a lot!