# How does Serde's deserialize method infer types?

Tags: rust, type-inference, serde

I was following some code examples on the Rust CSV crate's tutorial page, and the tutorial doesn't explain how this works:

```
type Record = HashMap<String, String>;

fn csv_to_record_table() -> Result<Vec<Record>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_path(r"h:\code\rust\csvtutorial\uspop.csv")?;
    let mut sheet = Vec::<Record>::new();
    for result in rdr.deserialize() {
        let record = result?;
        sheet.push(record);
    }
    Ok(sheet)
}
```

My code works, so I don't need a fix, but what I'm trying to understand is how `rdr.deserialize()` is able to infer that the type I want is `HashMap<String, String>`. I get from the documentation that if you pass it a hashmap, then it knows to use the column name as the key, and the field data as the value.

What I don't get is how `rdr.deserialize()` knows that that's what I'm trying to do without me rewriting that as `rdr.deserialize::<Record>()`. Is this a feature of Rust? Or is this something specific to Serde? How does it also know that I'm not trying to give it a `Vec<Record>`?

Comment: You've specified that `sheet` is `Vec<Record>`, thus any value pushed into it must be `Record`. `deserialize` returns an iterator of `Result<T, _>`, which you handle the error case, so `T` must be `Record`.

Comment: See also [Why does calling a method on a variable prevent Rust from inferring the type of the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55243660/155423)

Comment: You can *probably* write `Vec::new()` (no need for the type) as well. In fact, that whole thing can be `Ok(rdr.deserialize().collect()?)`

Comment: interesting...I tried the rdr.deserialize().collect()? and it says that it can't infer the type for the .collect. This reminds me of linq but I don't understand the examples that well. And that is correct, removing the type from the Vec initalizer works. FWIW I have rust-analyzer and it's showing me what types it's inferring, just how it's doing that is confusing, I kind of feel like it makes the code hard to read without rust-analyzer

Comment: Odd, swear I tested that.  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be7564bbe493c034216af84accc10949 Works though

Comment: That works. Is there something similar to .collect that could, say, collect this into a HashSet<Record> as opposed to Vic<Record>, similar to .Net's .ToHashSet, .ToArray, .ToList, etc, or would something like that need to be done with the for loop?

Comment: Yes, it’s called `collect`. Just change the `Vec` to `Hashset`

Comment: I tried that, the compiler gave me this: the trait `std::hash::Hash` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>`

Comment: Ah, that’s a different problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/27828487/155423

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I've since learned that instead of HashMap I could use BTreeMap, which implements .Hash, and so it can be placed in a HashSet. If I had enough knowhow with rust, I'd submit a pull request to add support for that in the IndexMap crate, which is better suited to what I'm doing.