# How to std::hash an unordered std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stl, std-pair

I want to be able to use a `std::pair` as a key in an unordered_container. I know that I could do this the following way:

```
template<typename T>
void
hash_combine(std::size_t &seed, T const &key) {
  std::hash<T> hasher;
  seed ^= hasher(key) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

namespace std {
  template<typename T1, typename T2>
  struct hash<std::pair<T1, T2>> {
    std::size_t operator()(std::pair<T1, T2> const &p) const {
      std::size_t seed(0);
      ::hash_combine(seed, p.first);
      ::hash_combine(seed, p.second);
      return seed;
    }
  };
}
```

However, I want the hashing to ignore the order of the elements in the `std::pair` (i.e., to return the same seed for `std::pair<A, B>` and `std::pair<B, A>)`.

One way I thought to achieve this is to apply some kind of ordering when creating my `std::pair<A, B>` (i.e., some kind of custom `std::make_pair`).
But this is too restrictive since objects `A, B` might not have an order.

### Q:

Is there a standard way to hash a `std::pair`, such that the order of elements is ignored and the same seed is returned either for `std::pair<A, B>` and `std::pair<B, A>`?

Comment: You could use `^` to combine the hashes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889238/why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes EDIT: Second thought: This may not be good for `std::pair<A, A>` since all pairs with equal values will have hash `0`.

Comment: @Wintermute Thanks for the reply, I've seen that thread, but as you've already mentioned this doesn't suit my needs due to the deterioration you've  also mentioned ;).

Comment: `to return the same seed for std::pair<A, B> and std::pair<B, A>` Why, if you don't mind me asking? What problem are you trying to solve where this (rather unusual) property would be of help?

Comment: @Wintermute That can be solved by a specialization taking only a single template argument, which does something different from the specialization taking two template arguments. And maybe a `static_assert` to make sure the user of the two-argument template doesn't provide the same types for both template arguments. Not perfect, but better than nothing I guess.

Comment: [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.java#379) does it by bytewise addition of the individual hashes, so that's probably not a completely insane solution.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Not mind at all, is for a collision tracker.

Comment: So how exactly would a "collision tracker" make use of this property? Suppose you managed to implement the hash the way you want - can you show an example of how you would use it?

Comment: Why not just `hash(first) + hash(second)`?

Comment: @HowardHinnant This is what I did, since the sum is commutative the order of the pair's values doesn't matter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't order the pairs, order the hashes:

```
namespace std {
  template<typename T1, typename T2>
  struct hash<std::pair<T1, T2>> {
    std::size_t operator()(std::pair<T1, T2> const &p) const {
      std::size_t seed1(0);
      ::hash_combine(seed1, p.first);
      ::hash_combine(seed1, p.second);

      std::size_t seed2(0);
      ::hash_combine(seed2, p.second);
      ::hash_combine(seed2, p.first);

      return std::min(seed1, seed2);
    }
  };
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2581657301b75cb7)

Comment: You could also order them via type_info::before, which eliminates half the hash calculation (and possibly even the "if" check, depending on how good the optimizer is).

Comment: @Nevin could you provide a live example please?

Comment: This solution does not scale from pairs to tuples of arbitrary length.