# Why map<pair<int,int>, int> works, but unordered_map<pair<int,int>> doesn't?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

`map<pair<int,int>, int>` compiles but `unordered_map<pair<int,int>>` has issues with hash function. What's really happening in the back?

Comment: C++ has a built-in `operator<` for pairs (lexicographic ordering, assuming the types of the pair support comparison by `operator<`) but it doesn't have a built-in hash for pairs and tuples. So you can use them in `map`s but not `unordered_map`s. Not sure exactly _why_ there isn't a built-in hash for pairs and tuples--hard to come down on a "right" default that balances speed and hash quality?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rcpp so please remove the tag (which I cannot do right now as there is pending-approval edit).

Comment: Duplicates: [Why can't I compile an unordered_map with a pair as key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32685540/995714), [Why did the C++ standards committee not include std::hash for pair and tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68320024/995714), [Why does std::map accept a std::pair as key, but std::unordered_map does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50163423/995714), [Why can't I compile an unordered_map with a pair as key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32685540/995714), [`pair<int,int>` pair as key of unordered_map issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4870437/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I compile an unordered\_map with a pair as key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685540/why-cant-i-compile-an-unordered-map-with-a-pair-as-key)

Comment: the solution is to provide the hash function yourself: [How to std::hash an unordered std::pair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28367913/995714), [Hash for a std::pair, for use in an unordered_map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45395071/995714)

Answer (score 0):

[`std::map<Key,T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) requires that the key type is comparable. The default comparator for [`std::map<Key,T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is [`std::less<Key>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), so you can use it with [`std::pair<T1,T2>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) because `std::pair` defines [`operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) (or `operator<=>` depending on your version of C++), making it comparable. Since the map is ordered, it must be able to compare the keys to know *how* they will be ordered internally, and it does this with the comparator.

[`std::unordered_map<Key,T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) on the other hand requires two different aspects from the `Key` type, it must be hashable and must also be comparable for equality. `std::pair<T1,T2>` does implement `operator==`/`operator<=>` but this alone is not enough for the type to be usable as the `Key` type. The standard library does not supply a specialisation of `std::hash` for `std::pair`, hence it will not compile (however, [boost does](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html), it simply combines the hash of `.first` and `.second`).

You can use `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, ...>` if want to, but you need to supply your own function for hashing this type, either by defining a functor to pass as a template argument to `std::unordered_map<>` or by defining your own custom specialisation of `std::hash<std::pair<int, int>>` directly.