# Why is ORing two ints considered a good hashing function?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, hash, bit-manipulation

One of my C# books (*C# 3.0 Cookbook* by *Hillyard and Teilhet*) in giving an example of a `Square` class writes the `GetHashCode` as

```
public override int GetHashCode ( ) 
{
    return this.Height.GetHashCode() | this.Width.GetHashCode();
}
```

I'm wondering why this is considered a good hash code. Becuase the table for an `|` operation is

```
x | y | x OR y
--------------
0 | 0 |   0
1 | 0 |   1 
0 | 1 |   1
1 | 1 |   1
```

which means that 3/4 of the time the result of the operation is `1`. So if you have miscellaneous `int`s  `w, x, y, z` that means the chance that `w | x == y | z` is not as small as it could be (if `^` was used, for example).

Is my understanding of this corret? Or is there a good reason why `|` is used for the hashing function?

Comment: It's not a good hash function. `^` would be better. However, keep in mind that `GetHashCode()` is just the first step in equality so returning a constant would also be an acceptable (but not good) hash code.

Comment: @Enigmativity That's for confirming what I thought was the case

Comment: Welcome to SO, Hillary:) I suspect nobody except Hillyard and Teilhet can explain why they prefer OR over XOR. I would use the latter, but you can do some benchmarking against `Distinct()` over a collection for example.

Comment: I will just put this here http://stackoverflow.com/q/5889238/3909293

Comment: While I don't know the context, `Square` sounds like the width and height ought to be equal. In that case, XOR would be a particularly poor hash combinator because it would just be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a horrible, horrible hash function, for exactly the reason you mention.  Certainly a mistake (or you should find a new book!).  You should submit it to the book's errata page:

http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596516109