# std::hash variations of object with arbitrary number of attributes of fundamental type

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, unordered-map, stdhash

### Discussion:

Let's say I have a `struct`/`class` with an arbitrary number of attributes that I want to use as key to a `std::unordered_map` e.g.,:

```
struct Foo {
  int    i;
  double d;
  char   c;
  bool   b;
};
```

I know that I have to define a hasher-functor for it e.g.,:

```
struct FooHasher {
  std::size_t operator()(Foo const &foo) const;
};
```

And then define my `std::unordered_map` as:

```
std::unordered_map<Foo, MyValueType, FooHasher> myMap;
```

What bothers me though, is how to define the call operator for `FooHasher`. One way to do it, that I also tend to prefer, is with `std::hash`. However, there are numerous variations e.g.,:

```
std::size_t operator()(Foo const &foo) const {
  return std::hash<int>()(foo.i)    ^
         std::hash<double>()(foo.d) ^
         std::hash<char>()(foo.c)   ^
         std::hash<bool>()(foo.b);
}
```

I've also seen the following scheme:

```
std::size_t operator()(Foo const &foo) const {
  return std::hash<int>()(foo.i)           ^
         (std::hash<double>()(foo.d) << 1) ^
         (std::hash<char>()(foo.c)   >> 1) ^
         (std::hash<bool>()(foo.b)   << 1);
}
```

I've seen also some people adding the golden ratio:

```
std::size_t operator()(Foo const &foo) const {
  return (std::hash<int>()(foo.i)    + 0x9e3779b9) ^
         (std::hash<double>()(foo.d) + 0x9e3779b9) ^
         (std::hash<char>()(foo.c)   + 0x9e3779b9) ^
         (std::hash<bool>()(foo.b)   + 0x9e3779b9);
}
```

### Questions:

1. What are they trying to achieve by adding the golden ration or shifting bits in the result of `std::hash`.
2. Is there an *"official scheme"* to `std::hash` an object with arbitrary number of attributes of fundamental type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple xor is symmetric and behaves badly when fed the "same" value multiple times (`hash(a) ^ hash(a)` is zero).  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952689/1774667) for more details.

This is the question of combining hashes.  `boost` has a hash_combine that is pretty decent.  Write a hash combiner, and use it.

There is no *"official scheme"* to solve this problem.

Myself, I typically write a super-hasher that can take anything and hash it.  It hash combines tuples and pairs and collections automatically, where it first hashes the *count* of elements in the collection, then the elements.

It finds `hash(t)` via ADL first, and if that fails checks if it has a manually written hash in a helper namespace (used for `std` containers and types), and if that fails does a `std::hash<T>{}(t)`.

Then my hash for `Foo` support looks like:

```
struct Foo {
  int    i;
  double d;
  char   c;
  bool   b;
  friend auto mytie(Foo const& f) {
    return std::tie(f.i, f.d, f.c, f.b);
  }
  friend std::size_t hash(Foo const& f) {
    return hasher::hash(mytie(f));
  }
};
```

where I use `mytie` to move `Foo` into a `tuple`, then use the `std::tuple` overload of `hasher::hash` to get the result.

I like the idea of hashes of structurally similar types having the same hash.  This lets me act as if my hash is transparent in some cases.

Note that hashing unordered meows in this manner is a bad idea, as an asymmetric hash of an unordered meow may generate spurious misses.

(Meow is the generic name for map and set.  Do not ask me why: Ask the [STL](http://nuwen.net/stl.html).)

Answer (score 5):

The standard hash framework is lacking in respect of combining hashes. Combining hashes using `xor` is sub-optimal.

A better solution is proposed in [N3980 "Types Don't Know #"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html).

The main idea is using the same hash function and its state to hash more than one value/element/member.

With that framework your hash function would look:

```
template <class HashAlgorithm>
void hash_append(HashAlgorithm& h, Foo const& x) noexcept
{
    using std::hash_append;
    hash_append(h, x.i);
    hash_append(h, x.d);
    hash_append(h, x.c);
    hash_append(h, x.b);
}
```

And the container:

```
std::unordered_map<Foo, MyValueType, std::uhash<>> myMap;
```