# Merge of String hashes into master hash

Tags: java, string, hashcode

Should a merge of hashes of two String objects be the same as a hash of their concatenation? I was using XOR ^ operator (as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889238/why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes)) and got a different result.

What I am doing wrong?

```
String a = "A";
String b = "B";
String ab = a+b;
int i = a.hashCode() ^ b.hashCode();

System.out.println(
    a.hashCode()+"\n"+
    b.hashCode()+"\n"+
    ab.hashCode()+"\n"
    i);
```

Comment: No. Why would you expect them to be the same? Did you check the documentation for `String.hashCode()`?

Comment: *"What I am doing wrong?"* Your thinking, is what you're doing wrong. Why would you think XOR'ing hashes would be the same. `String` can create the hash in any way it wants. It could send the text through a cryptographic function if it wanted to *(it won't, too slow)*. But as far as you're concerned, it might as well have. You should never expect any particular hash value for a particular text. New versions of Java may even change the algorithm used.

Comment: @Andreas Not really. The algorithm is in the documentation. It can't be changed now.

Comment: @shmosel Technically, nothing stops a new Java SE version JSR or JEP from changing the algorithm.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Technically, nothing stops the next JLS from swapping the meaning of `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of the question is wrong. The only hard requirement for `hashCode()` is that two objects that are equal (i.e., calling `a.equals(b)` returns `true`) has equal hash codes (i.e., `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` returns `true`.

In fact, by reading through [`String#hashCode()`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()), it's state that:

> The hash code for a String object is computed as
>   `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`
>
> using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

So clearly, concatinting two strings will not result in a string that has a hash code equal to the xor of hash codes of the strings that made it up.