# ^ operator in Swift

Tags: swift

Looking through the hashable protocol, and to make a matrix location struct to conform:

```
struct MatrixLocation: Hashable {
    let row: Int
    let col: Int
    var hashValue: Int { return row.hashValue ^ col.hashValue }
}
```

The hash value has the `^` operator.

What is the `^` operator in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is the XOR operator in Swift. Basically it compares the bits of the two operands, and for each bit, it sets the corresponding bit of the result to `1` if one of the two input bits is `1`, but the other is `0`. If both bits are `1` or both bits are `0`, it sets the bit in the result to `0`.

So if you have `0x49 ^ 0x13`, that would be 01001001 XOR 00010011, which would come out to 01011010, or `0x5a`.

Comment: Because it's a quick and easy way to combine the two existing hash values in a way that comes out relatively unique. If you just ORed them you'd end up with a disproportionate number of 1 bits, and if you ANDed them, you'd end up with a disproportionate number of 0 bits. Each bit has a 50/50 chance of being 0 or 1 in an XOR operation, unlike those two.

Comment: XOR is quick and easy, but not actually a good choice for combining hash values. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952689/77567) for an example of a much better hash combiner.