# How to handle overflow in GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, overflow, hashcode

I'm overwriting the `GetHashCode()` Function for my Vector class. Its just contaning 3 floats `X`, `Y`, `Z`. I'm wondering whats the best way to do so.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var sum = X + 3 * Y + 5 * Z;
    return sum.GetHashCode();
}
```

I need this to quickly find a Vector in a big-Collection.

I don't want to just return `X.GetHashCode()` or so, because this would lead to too many equals checks for straight lines.

The problem with my current implementation is that, if the floats are really big I might get an **integer overflow**.

- Is there a way to tell my compiler to just cut out any overflow?
- Is there a better Solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the `unchecked` keyword, and then combine the values. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode).

Comment: @Neijwiert seems good to me feel free to write an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, when we combine hash codes manually, we do it with **xor**:

```
public override int GetHashCode() =>
  X.GetHashCode() ^ Y.GetHashCode() ^ Z.GetHashCode();
```

See [Why is XOR the default way to combine hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889238/why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes) for details

*xor* never throws any exception. You can let .Net to combine for you:

```
public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(X, Y, Z);
```

Comment: How is it a better solution when pairs with the same value get 0 hashcode? suppose we have x,y,z = 2 and x,y,z = 3. Both get hashcode 0.

Comment: @Neijwiert: if `x.GetHashCode() == 0` and  `y.GetHashCode() == 0` but  `z.GetHashCode() == 2` or `3` we have `0 ^ 0 ^ 2 == 2` and `0 ^ 0 ^ 3 == 3`, you've probably mixed `^` and `&`

Comment: @Neijwiert actually they would not. if x,y,z = 2 x^y=0 but x^y^z=2 again.It' a slim solution thats why i prefer it. Every solution will have overlap since we put 96 bits of data in 32 bits. I have no time to determ right now wich will perform better

Comment: You're right, I forgot that after the first 2 it already turns to 0. It would however be a problem in case of a 2D vector though or anything with 2 fields.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to tell my compiler to just cut out any overflow?

Yes, you can use the [unchecked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) keyword for that. As @kalimag pointed out, only integral values throw exceptions on overflow.

> Is there a better Solution?

The proper way to combine hash values would be:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + X.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Y.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Z.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) for explanation.

Comment: `float` and `double` never throw overflow exceptions, they turn into negative or positive infinity. `checked`/`unchecked` only affects primitive integer types. Calling `GetHashCode()` on each individual `float` is probably still a good idea though to improve the quality of the combined hash code.

Comment: @kalimag you're right. But in this case the floats are converted to integral values and then do need to be unchecked for overflow. I edited the question to reflect your comment.