# Why does "unordered_map" with a "struct" as key run so slow?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have used (i, j, k) coordinates as key in an `unordered_map`. But when I insert more keys into it, it becomes much slower in a shocking magnitude (e.g. insert **10x** more keys and consumes **100x** more time, and even worse). The `unordered_map` now is the bottleneck of my program, so I want to find out how to improve it. Following is the minimal reproducible example of my problem:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

// define the key
struct key
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    key(int a,int b,int c): i(a),j(b),k(c){}
    bool operator==(const key& other_key) const{
        return i==other_key.i && j==other_key.j && k==other_key.k;
    }
};

// define a simple hash function for unordered_map
struct key_hash
{
    size_t operator()(const key& o) const{
        return o.i ^ o.j ^ o.k;
    }
};

// define unordered_map
unordered_map<key,int,key_hash> memory;

int main(int arg,char **argv){
    // accept arguments about how many keys should be inserted
    int I=atoi(argv[1]);
    int J=atoi(argv[2]);
    int K=atoi(argv[3]);

    double st=clock();
    for(int i=0;i<I;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<J;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<K;k++){
                memory[{i,j,k}]=i+j+k;
            }
        }
    }
    double et=clock();
    printf("time: %f",(et-st)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

I try following arguments and the result is:

| (I, J, K) | time (sec) |
| --- | --- |
| (1, 100, 100) | 0.013 |
| (10, 100, 100) | 1.285 |
| (100,100,100) | 327.178 |

The shocking thing is that when I increase `I` by **10x**, the time increases by **100x** and even worse. I also use python to run the same logic and get much more reasonable and better result. Following is the python code:

```py
import time
if __name__=='__main__':
    I=100
    J=100
    K=100
    memory={}
    st=time.time()
    for i in range(I):
        for j in range(J):
            for k in range(K):
                memory[(i,j,k)]=i+j+k
    et=time.time()
    print('time: {}'.format(et-st))
```

The result of python is in following table:

| (I, J, K) | time (sec) |
| --- | --- |
| (1, 100, 100) | 0.006 |
| (10, 100, 100) | 0.043 |
| (100,100,100) | 0.318 |

So in python the increase of `I` and the increase of time is in the same magnitude, which is reasonable. And the time python used is also significantly less.

In conclusion, is my code wrong or is `unordered_map` not suitable for my purpose? And how can I solve it?

Comment: Your hash function makes the same hash for lots of keys

Comment: Yes, bad hash function. Use a better `hash_combine`, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590677/how-do-i-combine-hash-values-in-c0x) or `boost::hash_combine`.

Comment: Also [Why is XOR the default way to combine hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889238/why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes).

Comment: Any permutation of `i`, `j` and `k` results in the same hash. With values up to 100 only the 7 least significant bits are filled resulting in 2^7 possible hashes which results in an average of 10^6 / 2^7 = 7812.5 keys per hash.

Comment: (A) above for the hash and (B) was the testing done with optimisation on?  Please include the compilation flags in the question.

Comment: Because of the bad hash key, performance tends towards O(n) linear search of a vector.  You may have better performance with a sorted vector and binary search.

Comment: Usually hash keys are calculated from summing values multiplied by relative prime numbers (which are ideally relative prime to the size of the container). E.g. try 3*i + 7*j + 11*k for your hash function.

Comment: The performance has much improved after using good hash function `boost::hash_combine`. Thanks everyone!