# How to get intersection of two Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have two integer arrays

```
    int A[] = {2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7};
    int B[] = {9, 2, 7, 6};
```

And i have to get intersection of these array.

i.e. output will be - 2,6,7

I am thinking to sove it by saving array A in a data strcture and then i want to compare all the element till size A or B and then i will get intersection.

Now i have a problem i need to first store the element of Array A in a container.

shall i follow like -

```
int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);
```

To get the size but by doing this i will get size after that i want to access all the elemts too and store in a container.

Here i the code which i am using to find Intersection ->

```
#include"iostream"

using namespace std;


int A[] = {2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7};
int B[] = {9, 2, 7, 6};

int main()
{
    int sizeA = sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);

    int sizeB = sizeof(B)/sizeof(int);

    int big =  (sizeA > sizeB) ? sizeA : sizeB;

    int small =  (sizeA > sizeB) ? sizeB : sizeA;

    for (int i = 0; i <big ;++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <small ; ++j)
        {
            if(A[i] == B[j])
            {
                cout<<"Element is -->"<<A[i]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You just need a bit for each position in a

Comment: This sort of question is frustrating because you have faulty assumptions, a poor description of your intended algorithm, a code example that isn't legal C, insufficient information about your arrays to determine the best algorithm,and a question title that bears little relationship to the question text. Google "XY Problem" and you will get an idea of what is wrong here.

Comment: @JimBalter Dont you understand the question? In simple ways i need a container in which i can store all Array elements of an Array in which size is unknown.

Comment: @JimBalter i Dont want to follow above approch which i have given in sample code now.

Comment: Just use a hash table for one array and iterate through the other. Runtime: O(n + m) w.h.p. optimal.

Comment: @NiklasB. Can you provide sample?

Comment: @Astro-Amit I wrote it down in an answer.

Comment: "Dont you understand the question?" -- Sigh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a [hash table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set):

```
#include <unordered_set>  // needs C++11 or TR1 
// ...
unordered_set<int> setOfA(A, A + sizeA);
```

Then you can just check for every element in `B`, whether it's also in `A`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeB; ++i) {
    if (setOfA.find(B[i]) != setOfA.end()) {
        cout << B[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Runtime is expected *O(sizeA + sizeB)*.

Comment: +1 for using showing a hash table with O(1) insertion and retrieval. I've always been worrying about O(log n) time using stl map.

Comment: Are there any dependencies if I use unordered_set<myObject> similar to < operator which is required for map<myObject> ?

Comment: @cegprakash yes, you need `operator==` and a matching template instance `std::hash<myObject>`

Comment: Thank you.. And are you sure that find() function is O(1) in an unordered_set?

Comment: @cegprakash why don't you just look it up? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find

Comment: I wanted you to look up. The Runtime you gave is incorrect. It'll take O(sizeA * sizeB).

Comment: @cegprakash No, it's correct: "Constant on average" Not sure what you're getting at there, note the word "expected" in my answer. You can also have [with high probability](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/With_high_probability), but then you need a more specialized hash table implementation

Comment: got it. Thank you.. I'm now wondering on how to implement errorless hash functions for user defined data types :|

Comment: @cegprakash Well errorless is not possible, but you can reduce collisions by using a good hash algorithm.  Unfortunately there is no `hash_combine` in the standard library yet, but you [can use the one from boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590677/how-do-i-combine-hash-values-in-c0x). [MurmurHash3](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) is also a very good general purpose hash function.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the two arrays

```
sort(A, A+sizeA);
sort(B, B+sizeB);
```

and use a merge-like algorithm to find their intersection:

```
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<int> intersection;
int idA=0, idB=0;

while(idA < sizeA && idB < sizeB) {
    if (A[idA] < B[idB]) idA ++;
    else if (B[idB] < A[idA]) idB ++;
    else { // => A[idA] = B[idB], we have a common element
        intersection.push_back(A[idA]);
        idA ++;
        idB ++;
    }
}
```

The time complexity of this part of the code is linear. However, due to the sorting of the arrays, the overall complexity becomes O(n * log n), where n = max(sizeA, sizeB).

The additional memory required for this algorithm is optimal (equal to the size of the intersection).

Answer (score 1):

> saving array A in a data strcture

Arrays *are* data structures; there's no need to save A into one.

> i want to compare all the element till size A or B and then i will get intersection

This is extremely vague but isn't likely to yield the intersection; notice that you must examine every element in both A and B but "till size A or B" will ignore elements.

> What approach i should follow to get size of an unkown size array and store it in a container??

It isn't possible to deal with arrays of unknown size in C unless they have some end-of-array sentinel that allows counting the number of elements (as is the case with NUL-terminated character arrays, commonly referred to in C as "strings"). However, the sizes of your arrays are known because their compile-time sizes are known. You can calculate the number of elements in such arrays with a macro:

```
#define ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof *(a))
```

...

> int *ptr = new sizeof(A);

[Your question was originally tagged [C], and my comments below refer to that]

This isn't valid C -- `new` is a C++ keyword.

If you wanted to make copies of your arrays, you could simply do it with, e.g.,

```
int Acopy[ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT(A)];
memcpy(Acopy, A, sizeof A);
```

or, if for some reason you want to put the copy on the heap,

```
int* pa = malloc(sizeof A);
if (!pa) /* handle out-of-memory */
memcpy(pa, A, sizeof A);
/* After you're done using pa: */
free(pa);
```

[In C++ you would used `new` and `delete`]

However, there's no need to make copies of your arrays in order to find the intersection, unless you need to sort them (see below) but also need to preserve the original order.

There are a few ways to find the intersection of two arrays. If the values fall within the range of 0-63, you can use two `unsigned long`s and set the bits corresponding to the values in each array, then use `&` (bitwise "and") to find the intersection. If the values aren't in that range but the difference between the largest and smallest is < 64, you can use the same method but subtract the smallest value from each value to get the bit number. If the range is not that small but the number of distinct values is <= 64, you can maintain a lookup table (array, binary tree, hash table, etc.) that maps the values to bit numbers and a 64-element array that maps bit numbers back to values.

If your arrays may contain more than 64 distinct values, there are two effective approaches:

1) Sort each array and then compare them element by element to find the common values -- this algorithm resembles a merge sort.

2) Insert the elements of one array into a fast lookup table (hash table, balanced binary tree, etc.), and then look up each element of the other array in the lookup table.

Comment: Isn't the question about C++?!

Comment: @NiklasB.The tag was [C] and the question was different when I typed this ... go look at the edit.

Comment: @NiklasB. What's your point? There's a finite rate and which I can read and type. What I wrote was valid when the question was asked and still contains valid information.

Comment: @NiklasB. I've edited it to identify the parts that do/don't apply to C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Sort both arrays (e.g., `qsort()`) and then walk through both arrays one element at a time.

Where there is a match, add it to a third array, which is sized to match the larger of the two input arrays (your result array can be no larger than the largest of the two arrays). Use a negative or other "dummy" value as your terminator.

When walking through input arrays, where one value in the first array is larger than the other, move the index of the second array, and vice versa.

When you're done walking through both arrays, your third array has your answer, up to the terminator value.

Comment: I think that the output might contain duplicate values.

Comment: @barakmanos It's easy to skip duplicate values in sorted arrays ... and if the arrays represent sets (which "intersection" somewhat implies), they won't have any duplicates.