# Functor for std::hash<boost::posix_time::ptime>

Tags: c++, boost, stdhash

I was wondering what would be the optimal way to calculate the hash, considering that the values of `ptime` that are used as the key differ mostly in the hour and date (minutes and seconds are usually 0).

I have done this but I feel that it is quite ugly and slow:

```
namespace std
{
    /**
     * Specialize std::hash for ptime
     */
    template<>
    class hash<boost::posix_time::ptime>
    {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const boost::posix_time::ptime& t) const
        {
            const auto dt = t.date();
            const auto ho = t.time_of_day().hours();
            return hash<int>()(dt.day_number()) ^ hash<int>()(ho);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keywords you should be looking are the "[avalanche effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect)" and "hash combine".

You probably should not design the hash function by yourself, since this area is thoroughly researched and studied. Just choose the function with a good avalanche effect, for example, [MurmurHash](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3).

Since you're already using boost, the [boost::hash_combine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) might be the most appropriate and useful solution for you ([also mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595226/419450)):

```
friend std::size_t hash_value(point const& p)
{
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    boost::hash_combine(seed, p.x);
    boost::hash_combine(seed, p.y);
    return seed;
}
```

More important, instead of using day_number and hours, you can use something like `total_nanoseconds()` or even get down to the internal system type and use that value for hashing, avoiding the artifical range decrease when you convert the real timestamp to days/hours.

Comment: Isn't total_nanoseconds() from time_duration -not ptime? therefore it would be only possible to get it from time_of_day(), isn't it?

Comment: You're correct, I looked at the wrong paragraph in documentation. But you got the idea: it's better to expand the hash input range to something like milliseconds or ticks, so the output is better distributed.