# Pair as a key in map for Memoization

Tags: c++, data-structures, types

I want to you use `unordered_map`for Memoization on a function `f(row, int)`. 
Unfortunately, I get a weird compilation error (very long and cryptic).

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>


using namespace std;

typedef vector<bool> row;

int main(void) {

    unordered_map< pair<int, row>, int > x;

}
```

Comment: What's the error ? Please paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key type for `std::unordered_map` needs to have an implementation of `std::hash`, I'd guess your error is telling you that `std::pair<int, row>` does not have an `std::hash` implementation. I don't think the standard specifies a specialization of `std::hash` for `std::pair` so you'll need to provide your own.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any ideas how to implement an effective hash function for a pair<int, vector<bool>> ?

Comment: The standard requires specializations of `std::hash` for both `int` and `std::vector<bool>` so you just need to combine them somehow, maybe like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590677/how-do-i-combine-hash-values-in-c0x - better support for building custom hash functions is proposed for a future version of the standard I believe.