# Efficient way to store C++ object with multiple fields of different types in std::set/std::map

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, stdmap, stdset

I have a general question. Let's assume I have a C++ class with multiple fields of different types. I want/need to store the objects of this class in `std::set` or `std::map` (in order to access them in O(log(N)).

In order to do it I need to overload `operator<` BUT what if `operator<` has no any logical meaning in my case? For example I have `class faceDescription` which contains fields like eye color, nose type etc.

The most obvious would be to implement `operator<` just by comparing each field like this:

```
if (fieldA < other.fieldA)
{
    return true;
}
else if (fieldA == other.fieldA && fieldB < other.fieldB)
...
```

and so on. But if I have many fields this method will be too long with too many branches, hardly readable and probably hard to maintain.

I was thinking about "packing" all the fields into a buffer and then compare it with something like `std::memcmp` but the point is that some fields may be pointers or different classes/structs.

**So my question:**

Is there an efficient and generic way to define a "*unique identifier*" to the class (maybe with some `std` methods) based on the fields values so that this "*unique identifier*" could be used to compare/sort objects of that class?

**EDIT**

Just an example which may explain the motivation and should be clear for everyone:

Assume video processing with face recognition so that the program receives face description object and it has to count how many times each face appeared during the given video. There may be thousands/millions of faces. So the efficient way to do it is to maintain a map of face description object as a key and number of appearance as a value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whey do you want to store them in a map if they don't have a natural order?

Comment: Why use an associative container if it doesn't make any sense to order them?

Comment: @JerryCoffin in order to access them in O(log(N))

Comment: What traits do you intend to use to find them?

Comment: @AlexLop. That doesn't really answer anything. Is there (for example) a reason you can't just store them in a vector and access them in O(1)?

Comment: BEWARE: at the opposite of other languages, `std::map` is an ordered map, and a simple mapping of keys to values is a `std::unordered_map` (since C++11). So I thing what you really want is an `unordered_map` (it exists in boost if you cannot use C++11, and MSVC alse had a version of it).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes. I just can't access it in O(1). I will give an example under **EDIT** in my question

Answer (score 2):

Your question is actually more like three questions packed in one:

#### I need to overload `operator<` BUT what if `operator<` has no any logical meaning in my case?

You don't really *need* to overload `operator<`, just provide a custom comparer to `std::set` or `std::map` (it's their second template argument); the default is `std::less` (which uses `operator<`), but you can provide any binary functor that defines a strict weak ordering relation between your elements.

#### The most obvious would be to implement `operator<` just by comparing each field [...]  But if I have many fields this method will be too long with too many branches, hardly readable and probably hard to maintain.

Unfortunately, C++ has no reflection (not even compile-time reflection, which would solve the situation here), so there's no easy way to make the "remember to add all the fields to the comparer whenever I add them to the `struct`".

However, the lexicografical comparison of a tuple of heterogeneous values is already solved (in C++11) by `std::tuple`; you can easily implement an `operator<` (or, FWIW, your custom comparer) by using `std::tie` and calling `<` on the returned tuples:

```
bool myComparer(const MyStruct &a, const MyStruct &b) {
    return std::tie(a.member1, a.member2, a.member3) < std::tie(b.member1, b.member2, b.member3);
}
```

You can find a similar example [at its reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) on cppreference.com.

#### Is there an efficient and generic way to define a "unique identifier" to the class (maybe with some `std` methods) based on the fields values so that this "unique identifier" could be used to compare/sort objects of that class?

Creating a unique identifier to compare/sort objects (i.e. satisfies the constraints of a strict weak ordering) depends on the exact details of your object - but probably, if you say that your objects *do not have* a meaningful ordering (besides an artificial one that you can impose by lexicographically comparing their components) you don't actually want such a thing; you just want to be able to use associative containers.

Enter `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set` (actually hashtables behind the standardese decoy names); what they require is a "somewhat unique" identifier that can quickly discriminate between different keys, AKA a hash function, and they can retrieve your element on average in O(1) time. In C++11, this function is `std::hash`.

The standard already defines overloads of it for primitive types plus some other random types; you can define your own `hash` (following the [standard signature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash); see at the bottom for an example specialization) by combining the hashes of the individual components of your `struct`; the combination can go from plain XOR or sum to something more elaborated [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590677/how-do-i-combine-hash-values-in-c0x).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I didn't mention it but I have a limitation. C++11 is not available for me at this moment that's why I referred to `std::map`/`std::set` and not their their C++11 'unordered' variants. However I wasn't familiar with `std::tie` and it looks like something that could work for me as it is more readable than many `if(...) else...` conditions. But it is also available only on C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own hash function taking class members as arguments and then, you can store your objects in a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) or [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) structure using these hash values as keys. So that you won't bother to compare new objects with the all objects in the map. You can also use [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for this particular purpose.

You can specialize std::hash for a user defined class (from the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct S
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<S>
    {
        typedef S argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t result_type;

        result_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
        {
            result_type const h1 ( std::hash<std::string>()(s.first_name) );
            result_type const h2 ( std::hash<std::string>()(s.last_name) );
            return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.first_name = "Bender";
    s.last_name =  "Rodriguez";
    std::hash<S> hash_fn;

    std::cout << "hash(s) = " << hash_fn(s) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Better use `std::unordered_map`, which accounts for hash collisions.

Comment: Do you know what is the probability of such 'hash' to return the same result for two different objects? Also if I have many fields, defining hash function for each type then calculating the general hash for the whole object will probably have even more complexity than the native field by filed compare.

Comment: @AlexLop., hash functions return pretty high integer values so it wouldn't be much problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using tuple?

```
// Multi-index map
map<tuple<int, char, float>, string> m;
m[make_tuple(31, 'd', 23.5f)] = "Just an idea";
```