# Unordered_map using 2D point for lookup

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for a way to use a std::unordered_map using a 2D point for the key.

My original plan was simply:

```
unordered_map<glm::ivec2, int> map
```

but it seems that isn't available. Is there a 2D type that would work with unordered_map?

Comment: You need to provide a hash function for your point type.

Comment: What do you mean by "that isn't available"?

Comment: I mean there isn't a hash function for glm::vec's @NeilButterworth

Comment: Then write it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38140932/214671

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` is a hashmap. By the properties of a hashmap to use a type as the key, there must be a hash and equals function defined for that type. By default `std::unordered_map` uses `std::hash` and `std::equal_to` for that purposes.

### The simple solution:

Luckily for you these appear to be already defined in `glm/gtx/hash.hpp` just include it before `unordered_map`. (See: https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/gtx/hash.hpp)

### The complex solution:

If those are not defined for a type, then you can use custom functions by overloading the template. This would look something like:

```
struct IVec2Hash {
   std::size_t operator()(const glm::ivec2 &v) const { /* implementation goes here */ }
};

struct IVec2Equals {
  bool operator()(const glm::ivec2 &a, const glm::vec2 &b) const { /* implementation */ }
};

std::unordered_map<glm::ivec2, int, IVec2Hash, IVec2Equals> ivec2_umap;
```