# How to use unordered_set for user defined types?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, unordered-set

I have the following struct:

```
struct prefix
{
    string_view value;
    int start_pos;
};
```

Is there a way to defined a method inside the structure to let me use an unordered_set like this:

```
unordered_set<prefix> my_set;
```

If it was just a set, all I had to do is provide the implementation to `operator<`. What I want to know is if there is an equivalent way for `unordered_set` as well.

P.S: I want it to use the standard hash implementation for string_view for the set.

Comment: The dupe is about `unordered_map`, but `unordered_set` has the exact same requirments.

Comment: You should also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590677/how-do-i-combine-hash-values-in-c0x) for how to combine hashes.