# Templates core headers bloating and explicit specialization of std::hash in cpp file in c++17

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, template-specialization

Suppose I got a core library in which I'm trying to add explicit specialization of `std::hash` for my core classes, including class `Foo` (and many others I'd like to also specialize `std::hash` with).

Foo.h

```
struct Foo
{
    ...
    size_t _id;
};
```

KeyHashing.h, lives in same library as Foo

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <unordered_map>

namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<Foo>
    {
        size_t operator()(const Foo& t) const noexcept; // Link error, unresolved external when used in client code
    };
    // extern template struct hash<Foo>; // error C2039 '()': is not a member of 'std::hash<Foo>'
}
```

Concerned about adding templates definitions in my header which are gonna get compiled in the translation units that they get included into and possibly increasing my total exe size and compile time, I'd like the implementation for `operator()` to live in KeyHashing.cpp (in the core library) and to look something like this.

KeyHashing.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590677/how-do-i-combine-hash-values-in-c0x
template <typename T, typename... Rest>
void HashCombine(size_t& seed, const T& v, Rest... rest)
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    (HashCombine(seed, rest), ...);
}

namespace std {
size_t hash<Foo>::operator()(const Foo& t) const noexcept // error C2039 when used with extern template struct hash<Foo> in header.
{
    std::size_t ret = 0;
    HashCombine(ret, t._id);
    return ret;
}
}
```

And in my client code (outside of core lib), I'd use `std::unordered_map` with my internal core classes as keys seamlessly.

So 2 questions:

1. Is the code bloating mentioned above a wrong assumption?
2. And if it isn't, how do I get this to compile/link without getting an unresolved
   external while keeping the definition in the .cpp? Because of course sending the definition in the header works great.

**UPDATE**

The code above doesn't link, with error

```
11>MyClass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned __int64 __cdecl std::hash<struct Foo>::operator()(struct Foo const &)const " (??R?$hash@UFoo@@@std@@QEBA_KAEBUFoo@@@Z) referenced in function "public: unsigned __int64 __cdecl std::_Uhash_compare<struct Foo,struct std::hash<struct Foo>,struct std::equal_to<struct Foo> >::operator()<struct Foo>(struct Foo const &)const " (??$?RUFoo@@@?$_Uhash_compare@UFoo@@U?$hash@UFoo@@@std@@U?$equal_to@UFoo@@@3@@std@@QEBA_KAEBUFoo@@@Z)
```

and as mentioned in comments the exe size may or may not be affected due to ODR, but the compile time is as relevant as any other metric so is there any syntax I'm missing here?

Comment: The One Definition Rule guarantees that "increasing my total exe size" will not be "possibly", but "never", in the described situation. This is a C++ requirement. The End.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what about compile time? Doesn't it take more time at link time to remove said definition duplication as per the One Definition Rule? Wouldn't it solve the issue if I were to put the definitions of the specializations and `HashCombine` in the .cpp?

Comment: Sure, compile time can easily baloon when templates are involved. But I find it more productive to invest in a bunch of networked servers with Threadrippers, using `distcc` to put together a compile farm, and just write clean, easy to read code that will not need a secret decoder ring and a magnifying glass to read.

Comment: Does this code compile, if you don't uncomment anything? You don't need `extern template` here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ODR doesn't guarantee or even vaguely promise anything about compiled code size.

Comment: You do with your hash implementation exactly the same thing you do with any function your library provides. Literally, no difference.

Comment: Sure it does, @n.m.couldbeanAI. ODR prevents the feared code bloat by disallowing multiple compiled instances of templated objects from winding up in the linked executable, due to being compiled in multiple translation units.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it doesn't link hence why I tried alternatives. Never been quite able to hit the right syntax. I'll post update with error message.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand the sentiment, but our local compile times are as critical a metric as any other so I find it unproductive to talk about boosting our build farm with steroids. Nor would I find it particularly more complex to read the same definition in header or cpp.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The standard doesn't allow multiple instances to be discovered by the program. It doesn't prohibit them from sitting idle in the executable and occupying space. It cannot, there is no vocabulary in the standard to express this requirement. It's a QoI issue. Linkers merge identical instantiations and inline functions not in order to be compliant, but in order to be useful. Sometimes they cannot do that (e.g. multiple shared libraries will all have their own copies of instances; there is no way to load just one copy in RAM, so there will be many copies, only one of them usable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out that my particular issue was the lack `__declspec(dllexport)` for the operator() that I defined in my core lib. So although j6t's answer can work, it turns out that I am able to have a specialization implementation out-of-line.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the implementation of a class template out-of-line, neither that of a (full) specialization. Have the specialization delegate to a function (non-template), which you can then implement out of line. Something like this (includes omitted for brevity):

KeyHashing.h:

```
size_t HashFoo(const Foo&) noexcept;

namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<Foo>
    {
        size_t operator()(const Foo& t) const noexcept
        { return HashFoo(t); }
    };
}
```

KeyHashing.cpp:

```
size_t HashFoo(const Foo& t) noexcept
{
    // your implementation goes here
}
```

Comment: Still getting an unresolved external for the delegated function HashFoo in the client code. LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "unsigned __int64 __cdecl HashFoo(struct Foo const &)" (?HashFoo@@YA_KAEBUFoo@@@Z) referenced in function "public: unsigned __int64 __cdecl std::hash<struct Foo>::operator()(struct Foo const &)const " (??R?$hash@UFoo@@@std@@QEBA_KAEBUFoo@@@Z)

Comment: I believe there's something weird with my setup, because just creating a normal function and implementing in source file KeyHashing.cpp and using it normally in client code gives an unresolved external.

Comment: I just needed to actually export the symbol in dll builds for the library.